# Refactoring to Generic Methods with Delegate Parameters in C#

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

So I have the methods below and I've having trouble converting them to use a generic dbcontext. Any thoughts here?

```cs
       public static Task ExecuteDbContextAsync(Func<OrderingDbContext, Task> action)
            => ExecuteScopeAsync(sp => action(sp.GetService<OrderingDbContext>()));

        public static Task ExecuteDbContextAsync(Func<OrderingDbContext, ValueTask> action)
            => ExecuteScopeAsync(sp => action(sp.GetService<OrderingDbContext>()).AsTask());

        public static Task ExecuteDbContextAsync(Func<OrderingDbContext, IMediator, Task> action)
            => ExecuteScopeAsync(sp => action(sp.GetService<OrderingDbContext>(), sp.GetService<IMediator>()));

        public static Task<T> ExecuteDbContextAsync<T>(Func<OrderingDbContext, Task<T>> action)
            => ExecuteScopeAsync(sp => action(sp.GetService<OrderingDbContext>()));

        public static Task<T> ExecuteDbContextAsync<T>(Func<OrderingDbContext, ValueTask<T>> action)
            => ExecuteScopeAsync(sp => action(sp.GetService<OrderingDbContext>()).AsTask());

        public static Task<T> ExecuteDbContextAsync<T>(Func<OrderingDbContext, IMediator, Task<T>> action)
            => ExecuteScopeAsync(sp => action(sp.GetService<OrderingDbContext>(), sp.GetService<IMediator>()));
```

this is the method they are calling:

```cs
        public static async Task ExecuteScopeAsync<TDbContext>(this IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, Func<IServiceProvider, Task> action)
            where TDbContext : DbContext
        {
            using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TDbContext>();

            try
            {
                //await dbContext.BeginTransactionAsync();

                await action(scope.ServiceProvider);

                //await dbContext.CommitTransactionAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //dbContext.RollbackTransaction();
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I tried something along the lines of this for the first one (along with many other iterations), but can't seem to get the syntax right

```cs
        public static Task ExecuteDbContextAsync<TDbContext>(Func<TDbContext, Task> action) where TDbContext : DbContext 
            => ExecuteScopeAsync<TDbContext>(sp => action(sp.GetService<TDbContext>()));
```

Comment: Is there a compilation error?

Comment: There's nothing to generalise here. Nothing is duplicated. In each of the methods you are doing something very different (calling vs not calling `AsTask`, passing vs not passing `sp.GetService<IMediator>()`, and whether the action returns a `Task` or `Task<T>`).

Comment: @Sweeper i just realized i hadn't posted the calling method. the issue is that this project doesn't have access to `orderingdbcontext` so i need to give it a gneric dbcontext and pass it the proper instance in the calling project

Comment: There's no point accepting a value task to always turn it into a task anyway.  By accepting it you're implying you're able to use it without turning it into a task (at least some of the time).  If you can't, just have the caller turn it into a task so they have no illusions as to whether they can actually avoid constructing a task.

Comment: Ah, yup i see what you mean now. thanks for the insight!